# How can I set 2 pieces of text next to each other?

Tags: minipage, alignment, text, vertical

I am new to LaTeX with very little knowledge. I've been experimenting with techniques like minipage, grouping, flushleft/flushright and others to get to have 2 pieces of texts (I like to think of it like individual textboxes as they would called in MS Word) next to each other, aligned at the top.

I can't provide any example in LaTeX as my knowledge is very limited.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you add a screenshot or freehand drawing of the result you are looking for?

Comment: Welcome here ! There are several ways to achieve what you want. And it's hard for us to imagine what you've in mind. Does a two column format fits your requirements ?

Comment: If you are doing translations, paracol is the package of choice.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your responses. I was looking for something like David Carlisle posted, with 2 text pieces right next to each other. I also saw another really helpful answer a couple hours ago but it is deleted now. John Kormylo, can you please explain the usage of the paracol package?

Comment: @Piroooh Two columns is what I have in mind, but not consistent 2 columns on the entire document. 2 columns of text for half a page maybe, then normal text with normal width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\parskip{1cm}

\section*{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{4cm}}
\raggedright
some text here on the left some text here on the left   &
\raggedleft
some more text on the right some more text on the right
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{4cm}}
\centering
some text here on the left some text here on the left   &
\centering
some more text on the right some more text on the right
\end{tabular}

\section*{parbox}

\parbox[t]{3cm}{
\raggedright
some text here on the left some text here on the left}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\parbox[t]{4cm}{
\raggedleft
some more text on the right some more text on the right}

\parbox[t]{3cm}{
\centering
some text here on the left some text here on the left}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\parbox[t]{4cm}{
\centering
some more text on the right some more text on the right}

\section*{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
\raggedright
some text here on the left some text here on the left
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
\raggedleft
some more text on the right some more text on the right
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
\centering
some text here on the left some text here on the left
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
\centering
some more text on the right some more text on the right
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

Comment: `\section*{minpage}` -> `\section*{minipage}`, please. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat it's Schrödinger's "i" it is there until you look for it.

Comment: Purely imaginary, I think.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat seamless repair completed. No one will notice.

Comment: I always thought imaginary i's need to be upright. Yours looks italic, almost egregious... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your response! That is one way of doing it, I tried it.